# In Linux guest on windows host: filelocks created by emacs inhibit editing of corresponding files using emacs and are unremovable

Tags: filesystems, virtualbox

After upgrading virtual box guest to Debian 11 on windows 10 host and updating all emacs packages I was not able to edit org files in a shared folder for which earlier a filelock was created and not removed even though I'm certainly the only user on this virtual machine. Emacs works fine when creating and editing new files.

I tried to `sudo rm -f`, but Operation was not permitted. `lsattr` and `sudo chattr -i` resulted in Operation not supported.

Editing and saving in emacs did not remove filelocks. However, I was able to edit them using nano.
How to clean up this annoying mess?

Answer (score 0):

After trying quite a while I realized that attribrutes are filesystem dependent as well as the format of filelocks (link vs "real" file). Deleting the file locks in the host system solved the issue.